# What will happen when the Code Names of the Ubuntu releases get to Z

Tags: release-management

The last release was **Natty Narwhal** (Letter N) for the 11.04. Then it was **Oneiric Ocelot** (Letter O) for the 11.10. This time, the newest one will be **Precise Pangolin** (Letter P) for the 12.04.

At this pace, what will happen when Ubuntu gets to Z? Will it start with numbers (007 Edition), will it start with double letters (AA Battery), or will it start from the beginning (Amazing Apple)? What will happen?

Comment: I'm hoping they will go with the Swedish letters **Å Ä Ö**. That would be awesome!

Comment: How about we just md5 the version number and use that... Ubuntu 17.04 (17 and 04) would be "Ubuntu **70efdf2ec9b086079795c442636b55fb 7d0665438e81d8eceb98c1e31fca80c1**" - i tell you the more I think about this the more I think it'll be the only sensible solution.

Comment: @rlemon: Actually 17.04 would be called Zombie Zebra (or something like that), but the 17.10 release would need another naming convention (or reset of the current one).

Comment: Can't we just take the Apple approach and add a **S** to the end of everything to denote a newer version? 12.10 could be **Precise Pangolin S**

Comment: Oh my, this is just **pure** speculation. The entire thing.

Comment: Reminds me of speculation about when Apple is going to run out of big cats to name their OSs after.

Comment: Let's hope we all speak Chinese by then!

Comment: Don't everybody knows that the mayan calendar predicts we will all be dead by the end of the year? We won't see the version 13.04...

Comment: 13.04 **Misinformed Mayans**

Comment: Oh !My flag accepted :)

Comment: We may have some extra time: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-February/036537.html

Comment: 17.10 (released today) is Artful Aardvark. The only option I can think of for 18.04 is Bashful BB.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## Artful Aardvark

That gets a lot tougher after AA.

But seriously, there are plenty of other verbs, adjectives and animals for each letter, so I expect it stay the same for 17.10.

And remember that is a *long* time (that's like a hundred years in Internet years) so Ubuntu might be doing something completely different by then.

<sub>Note: I look forward to you accepting (or down-voting) this in ~60 months time. *Puts it on his calendar!*</sub>

Comment: Briljant Oli! :D Abiding Abobat , Acurate Acuchis ...

Comment: In fact 17.10 is "Artful Aardvark".

Answer (score 52):

## Astonishing Antelope

As questions go - this pretty much will be a decision made by Mark Shuttleworth himself.

> Maybe we could start doubling the initial like in Aalenian Aal or
> Aalenian Aardvark  We could restart using flowers or plants instead of
> animals. e. g. Apologetic Anemone  For release 17.10 i suggest
> Ambitious Aye Aye  Maybe: Awesome Alebrije?  I like the idea of using
> plants next. Or perhaps rocks/minerals.

Thus as you have indicated we are in the realms of speculation.

On the link below - the wrap around to A is described up to F - **Flying Fox**, etc., i.e., **Ubuntu 20.04**

What is beyond that - happy speculating.

---

Useful link:

1. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames

Comment: Nice. Can't wait till they get to Aaargh Aaargh! ;)

Comment: @carleeto sounds like the pirated edition.

Comment: So, it seems that it's `Artful Aardvark`?

Answer (score 46):

It could just follow ASCII, and ultimately Unicode, order.

- ...
- Xenophobic Xenopus
- Yawning Yak
- Zealous Zebra
- [lumsy [aribou
- \ashful \ackslash
- ]ashing ]oberman
- ...
- ಠ ಠ
- ...

This may eventually require genetic engineering to breed new animals with appropriate names.

Comment: Great, that's two sites where my highest scoring answer is [a joke](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8550545/827263).  8-)}

Comment: Squares! Squares follow me anywhere!

Comment: Alas, the XX, YY, and ZZ releases didn't follow my suggestions; they were Xenial Xerus (16.04), Yakkety Yak (16.10), and Zesty Zapus (17.04, not yet released), respectively. But fear not -- the Law Of Averages guarantees that 17.10 will be [lumsy [aribou. (That's how it works, right?)

Answer (score 24):

I think we need to use **adverbs** and start over with A's.

- Actively Aggressive Alligator
- Badly Bristled Badger
- Completely Crazy Chicken

and so on...

I don't think people use adverbs enough in conversation, especially programmers like me.

Comment: Keep up making Adverbs!!, It seems Great to me :-D

Comment: Delightfully Delicious Duck!  Um, that one might go too far for some people.

Comment: Easily Entertained Elephant

Comment: Famously Friendly Finch

Comment: Giftedly Graceful Giraffe

Answer (score 16):

Let's just get past the end of the Mayan calendar first, and then we'll worry about the Z of Ubuntu. It would be nice if the Z of Ubuntu would get as much attention as the end of the Mayan calendar though. It is actually somewhat similar. We have the 6-month cycle, the 24 month cycle and the big cycle, which is the turn of the alphabet :)

[image: Countdown to Catastrophe]

[(Source)](http://bizarro.com/2009/12/30/countdown-to-catastrophe/)

What do you think Mark Shuttleworth thought when he came up with the Adjective Animal scheme? The guy on the right does have the same cool attitude that the SABDFL has, doesn't he? :)

Comment: Yes but... Who is this SABDFL guy you talking about? :-}

Comment: @Prasad: SABDFL is "Self-Appointed Benevolent Dictator for Life", the official title of Mark Shuttleworth, founder of Cannonical, in the Ubuntu project. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_Dictator_for_Life

Comment: thanks, (this is the 3rd attempt to comment this!) looks like i dropped almost every little intel behind by catching those big ones! :-)

Answer (score 6):

How about this! in maths after number 9, 10 comes. that means 1 and 0, as in the example ubuntu will be **Amazing Badger, Amazing Catfish**  :-)

Comment: The thought it nice. But this means that the sequence is more like: `00, 11, 22, ..., 99` and then goes to `01, 02, ...` Not very math-like.

Comment: Amazing Catfish?! :v U r high bro

Comment: someone should have a drink...at least me :3

Answer (score 5):

I suppose Apple will have to consider the same sort of thing eventually, when they run out of cats.  Maybe they'll have a "Schrodinger's Cat" and then move on to something else.  (Come to think of it, I wish WE could have a "Schrodinger's Cat!"  Maybe that'll have to wait for "Ubuntu for Quantum Computing.")

Comment: Why would they run out of cats, are they currently using staples? http://xkcd.com/262/

Answer (score 2):

*It is most likely that Mark will start using Caribbean terminologies as we have such an extensive vocabulary to choose from in our dialects.
I expect that he will probably start with **Restarting Rastaman** after Z, to signify the switch to the new naming scheme.*

--

On a more serious note, by the time that happens, we will likely be advanced in many other areas, or maybe the world might have ended - in other words, we just don't know. It's like Ubuntu will just start using animals beginning with A and going down, or switch to just descriptive words.

Answer (score 1):

## Aquatinted Avocado

Im thinking after all the animal names get over, we will have  `<verb> <plant>`

Like this:

- Aquatinted Avocado
- Baffling Blueberries

And so on

---

<sub>**Offtopic**</sub>

<sub>When we finish all the names. We should make something like the [Pokérap](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eINaziAt8yg). Maybe we can call it the UberRap</sub>

Answer (score -2):

I'd advised to call it:

**Autistic Aardvark**

That would rise autism awareness and PRs for Canonical which could donate to some organizations.