# What version of Ubuntu comes after 'Z'?

Tags: release-management

I know that the Ubuntu names follow alphabetical order.  Example: 12.04 was precise pangolin; 14.04 was trusty tahr; 16.04 is xenial xerus; 16.10 is yakkety yak.  My question is, what's coming after we pass 'Z'?  What will they do for 17.10 and 18.04 LTS?

P.S.:  I did read [What will happen when the Code Names of the Ubuntu releases get to Z](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113194/what-will-happen-when-the-code-names-of-the-ubuntu-releases-get-to-z).  If you want to dupe this, go ahead, but the remember that the answers back then were totally speculative.  One person even suggested the world might have ended by then.  Is this really a duplicate?

Comment: There is still no canonical (hah!) answer yet. We'll see when it happens.

Comment: All answers are speculative, because the names are decided by a single person when the new development version opens up. And questions about future Ubuntu versions are off topic.

Comment: Start a bounty on it if you want an update.

Comment: That's good to know, @dobey.  I honestly didn't know how the names are decided.  (Which is why I asked the question... :) )

Answer (score 1):

It's just a name and probably they will break the rule and make up a new rule, but definitely there is no relation between Ubuntu and the end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they will start using double letter prefixes, similar to column 27 of a spreadsheet. Aardvark, abalone, accentor, etc.